# How to create a Contact Us form in our SharePoint 2013 Public site?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

How to create a Contact Us form in our SharePoint 2013 Public site?

My client wants to develop only Using CEWP / SharePoint designer Web Part. Also he wants to use this form for anonymous user too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With assumptions that - "contact form details will be stored in a list and email may need to sent to person filling form and administrator"

1. Create appropriate list with required fields like Name of person, email address, Phone no, Subject, Comments
2. Give "anonymous users" access to add item to the new list. [Give access to anonymous users](http://www.topsharepoint.com/anonymous-access-for-lists)
3. Create form either using html using CEWP or Data Form Web Parts [Data Form Web parts](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Customize-Data-Views-and-forms-using-SharePoint-Designer-4201233c-ce24-42c2-9f2a-31f202c440cc)
4. Modify default list view to show records created by current user [Me] only
5. Create Workflow to send email to person filling form and customer support team.

Comment: I would suggest using Captcha, the solution will work but it is prone to injection attacks